# Add a Filter for Date Range option in a list

Tags: web-part, filter, date

Here is a little background on the task:

My client has a sharepoint site that has a list of data. One of the columns or fields is a date field, this date is entered manually using MM/DD/YY Format.

My client has requested me to add an option where they could filter the columns by a range of dates on the webpart view.

I read this guide: https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/pages/sharepoint-list-filtering-by-date-range.aspx and i got it to work, but it seems to be a bit buggy, meaning that sometimes the list will not get filtered by the specified dates..

Another issue with this method is that there is no Submit/Go button.

FROM: [ Text Field ] TO: [ Text Field ] [GO Button]

My client would love to have something like the example above where there are two text fields next to each other and a button that they can click to make the filter activate.

I searched for hours and hours and was not able to find something like this.

Do you guys know of a solution and if so, provide me with a link or guide, on how to achieve this problem? Thanks

**EDIT:**
It seems that there is a Apply Filters Button Web Part that does what i need. I added it and it seems to work Okay. I have to click Apply Filters TWICE in order for it to work.. ***weird huh? is there a fix for that?***

FYI: i followed the guide linked above and just added the apply filters button.

Answer (score 1):

Okay i fixed it,

It was because i was adding the date filter web parts to the library itself, and i was supposed to create a page for it and add my web-parts in there.